# How to load balance automatically in consumer by using KAFKA

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, stateless

**Here are my tasks:**

file_1: [task_1_1, task_1_2, ...]

file_2: [task_2_2, task_2_2, ...]

...

file_n: [task_n_1, task_n_2, ...]

Now I want to run file tasks in sequence (different files' task can be handled at the same time). How should I design the KAFKA topic or partition to make this happen OR do you have other MQ options for me:

1. Every consumer process is stateless.
2. Every tasks will be handled at least once.
3. It will automatically load balance after the consumer process is killed, restarted, or add new one.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These questions are addressed quite well in the Kafka docs. Some of the questions you bring up are basic Kafka features you can read about (Consumer groups autobalancing for instance and message delivery guarantees). See: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/